# Creating a second dataframe considering 2 conditions from first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a main DataFrame and I have found some rows that I dont want.
I have found those conditions in the code below:

```
df.query("group == 'treatment' and landing_page != 'new_page'") 
df.query("landing_page == 'new_page' and group != 'treatment'")
```

Now I want a `df2` considering the entire `df` **EXCEPT** those rows given in the code above.
I am getting a hard time trying to create this `df2`. Any lights?

My actual code:

```
df2 = df.query("group == 'treatment' and landing_page == 'new_page'") and df.query("group == 'control' and landing_page == 'old_page'")
```

I am receiving this error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: What if you use `&` instead of `and`?

Comment: actually created a df2 with NAN values on every column and row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `query` to `eval`, and invert the mask when indexing `df`.

```
m1 = df.eval("group == 'treatment' and landing_page != 'new_page'") 
m2 = df.eval("landing_page == 'new_page' and group != 'treatment'")

df_out = df[~(m1 | m2)]
```

---

Or, a little more generically,

```
stmts = [
    "group == 'treatment' and landing_page != 'new_page'",
    "landing_page == 'new_page' and group != 'treatment'"
]

df_out = df[~np.logical_or.reduce([df.eval(stmt) for stmt in stmts])]
```

Comment: thank you very much! It worked but I didnt understand the solution very well... would you mind to explain? :)

Comment: @LeandroBaruch `eval` returns True wherever the condition holds. You then invert the mask to get all rows where the condition isFalse.